# Google play information

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know if it's possible to get any information about users who installed my application from Google play. I know I can get statistic about downloads and everything, but I need more specific information. I am developing security layer for my application which would check phone from which application is running and compare it to which phone was installed from Google play. If it's not same phone then it was copied or cracked and install to another phone.

I know that I can get a lot of information from the phone ([Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)), but what about from Google play so I can compare this informations.

Is this possible? To get enough information to be 100% sure, that this phone is the phone to which application was installed?

Comment: "I would like to know if it's possible to get any information about users who installed my application from Google play" -- AFAIK, no, but this sounds like you should be using the license verification system rather than rolling your own: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Licensing library may suit your needs. It has a flexible licensing policy that let's you decide what should happen if, for example, it finds out that the user hasn't actually purchased your app.

You can read more about it here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try like you said.